# RKHS norm of a constant function?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Given a reproducible kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) with a constant function in this RKHS, is there an analytical expression of the RKHS norm of the constant function?

Comment: Why don't you try to evaluate some norms yourself? Pick your favourite RKHS, look up how its norm is defined and evaluate the expression on a constant function.